# Serving mp3 to mobile Safari browser in Java using Jersey

Tags: java, mobile-safari, jax-rs, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I am having trouble with this code,

```
@Path("/play")
public class Player {

    @GET
    @Produces("audio/mpeg")
    public Response get(@DefaultValue("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Music\\sample.mp3") @QueryParam("file") String file) {
        File song = new File(file);
        return Response.ok().entity(song).build();
    }
}
```

Chrome is able to play the content returned from this, but Safari mobile can't.

When I move the sample.mp3 into static web folder it is able to play in Safari mobile browser.

How can I get mobile Safari to play audio returned using JAX-RS?

Comment: When you serve the sample.mp3 file statically to Safari mobile, is there a way you can inspect the HTTP headers? Perhaps this info could shed some light on what safari mobile is expecting.

Comment: @broc.seib I never did  a follow up on this question. I ended up using  `AudioAttributes` and `EncodingAttributes` classes to convert the file to the right codec. It would be nice to have a library that could inspect a the codec of a file and say which devices can play it. I'll post my code in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `AudioAttributes` and `EncodingAttributes` classes to convert the file to the right codec. It's pretty slow and wastes a lot of storage because a new file has to be create each time a song is played. I'll probably change this code later so that the files are cached after converted. Then before I convert I check if I already converted. Also it would be nice to test if the raw file is compatible with the device before converting it. Here's current the code.

```
    @GET
    @Path("/audio")
    @Produces("audio/mpeg")
    public Response getAudio(
            @DefaultValue("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Music\\sample.mp3") @QueryParam("file") String file,
            @DefaultValue("medium") @QueryParam("quality") String quality) throws EncoderException, IOException {
        File song = new File(file);
        File rootMusicDir = new File(AUDIO_PATH);
        File rootVideoDir = new File(VIDEO_PATH);
        if (!directoryService.isSubDirectory(rootMusicDir, song) && !directoryService.isSubDirectory(rootVideoDir, song)) {
            return Response.status(500).build();
        }

        AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
        audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
        if (quality.equalsIgnoreCase("high")) {
            audio.setBitRate(new Integer(256000));
            audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
            audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
        } else if (quality.equalsIgnoreCase("medium")) {
            audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
            audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
            audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
        } else {
            audio.setBitRate(new Integer(64000));
            audio.setChannels(new Integer(1));
            audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(22050));
        }

        EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
        attrs.setFormat("mp3");
        attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
        Encoder encoder = new Encoder();

        String random = new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
        File songMP4 = new File(TEMP_PATH + file.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z ]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "+") + random);
        encoder.encode(song, songMP4, attrs);
        return Response.ok().entity(songMP4).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what the root cause of your problem was? I don't quite follow why re-encoding the file should solve the problem? From what I understood, you have an .mp3 which works fine in Safari mobile when served statically, but not when served as per your code above.  I presume, therefore, that your original .mp3 is encoded in a fashion that iOS can cope with (or else the statically served file would not play correctly).

Could there be an issue with the headers that you are sending along with the served .mp3?  The reason I ask is that I have a similar problem serving an mp3 to mobile Safari which is served by a Perl script. Works fine when files statically served. When the same file is served using Perl it gives 404 in Safari mobile (Safari on OSX works fine).

Comment: Your need to support byte-range requests. Apache and most other static file server software support it.